# Meaning of: "If you could, I'd want yours."

Tags: meaning

In tv series "Friends" season 2 episode 2, Monica says as follows after her parents went, because her parents are so tricky to her.

> Boy, I know they say you can't change your parents,... boy, if you could, I'd want yours.

I think the meaning of that is "If I could change my parents, I would select your parents".

But she said "if you could", not "if I could".

Why say it like that?

[Reference to subtitles](https://fangj.github.io/friends/season/0102.html)

Comment: This use of *you* is explained here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106323/using-you-and-your-as-a-representation-for-yourself-and-everyone-in-general

Comment: She means "If one could" (if it were possible), but it's much more common in everyday conversation to use _you_ in this sense.